# Why does marshal.dump (or load) loose the 'link' to my class after touching (and reloading) a rb-file in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The scenario is not too complex:

I have a cache, that I save and load with MARSHAL.dump and / load.

The cache itself is a hash `{ <String> =: <Manifest::Js::Source> }`

Everything works (creating, reading and saving the cache back to the file).

Until I touch a source file of the project. Then Marshal.dump gives me the error:

```
"Manifest::Js::Source can't be referred to"
```

All other things still work as expected.This state remains until I restart the Rails server, then Marshal.dump finds Manifest::Js::Source again.

I can reproduce this behavior with
Rails 3.x / Ruby 2.3 / Windows
and
Rails 7 / Ruby 2.7.7 / Linux

For me it looks like `Marshal` keeps a reference of `Manifest::Js::Source` intern, that is broken when the source is reloaded in development.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT - after further investigation:**

I store the cache as instance variable in Rails.application, to.

After touching the source code and auto loading, the classes in the cached hash are kind of zombies …

Or have you ever seen that `value.is_a?(value.class.name.constantize) => false`?

The next step I did was replacing all those 'zombie'-entries with new instances of  `Manifest::Js::Source`

```
source_file_cache.to_a.each {|k, s|
    source_file_cache[k]=s.class.name.constantize¹.new(s) unless s.is_a?(Source)
}

¹ s.class.new(s) produces just an other zombie …
```

Now the cache hash is clean (or seems to be), but Marshal.dump is still complaining with  "Manifest::Js::Source can't be referred to"

Comment: When you reload your code the object_id of all the classes/modules change so this isn't completly unexpected. Zeitwerk literally re-assigns all the constants to new class/module objects. Do you really need to use Marshal for caching or could you just store serialized data (like JSON) instead?

Comment: @max: fun fact: I don't need the cache at all. I just use it, 'cause I have it. The cache is inside the module since years, and just made this problems, when I made some changes in this module now. Not so fun fact: it took me 2 days to find, because I was searching in complete wrong part of code. Putting the module in the auto_load_once path should do it, to.